# Will the PHP 5.5 opcache be shared across processes with FastCGI (mod_fcgi)?

Tags: php, fastcgi

My website is running on PHP 5.5 with FastCGI (`mod_fcgi`). I'm aware that other opcache types (like APC) doesn't work well as **memory is not shared between php-cgi processes** ([here](http://www.brandonturner.net/blog/2009/07/fastcgi_with_php_opcode_cache/)).

I'm using PHP 5.5 built-in OPcache. Is the memory shared between processes or this is exactly the same problem of APC/Xcache with `mod_fcgi`?

Is there any way to test it?

Answer (score 6):

I have never understood why this was even entertained as a possibility, it is not a realistic possibility:

Both APC and Opcache have several forms of shared memory, their defaults and the most suitable kind is mmap'd memory, but for all kinds of strange reasons they need to support inferior kinds, none of these inferior kinds leave a possibility (even an unrealistic one) for this to work.

When it comes to mmap...

### APC

If you do not provide a file mask APC uses anonymous shared mapping, you cannot share this across distinct process boundaries, not possible.

If you do provide a file mask, APC uses unsynchronized shared mapping, it doesn't make sense to try and share that across distinct process boundaries since it will nearly always contain a corrupted shadow of the mapped memory, that's the nature of unsynchronized.

### Opcache

Doesn't provide you with any of the non-options that APC tried to provide, all mapping is done anonymously.

### Solution

Use a sane webserver such as nginx/lighthttpd, and use `fpm`, included with PHP.

FPM's process model allows the child processes it forks to have a common cache, problem solved, applicable to both APC and Opcache.